# Point (c) in proposition IV.2.2, page 300 of Hartshorne - can someone help me understand this point about wild ramification?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm dealing with the proof of proposition IV.2.2, page 300 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. Specifically, I'm having problems with point (c). I report here the details for this point:
let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite separable morphism of curves. Let $e_P$ denote the ramification index at $P$. Then

- if $f$ is tamely ramified at $P$ then $length(\Omega_{X/Y})_P=e_P-1$
- if $f$ is wildly ramified at $P$ then $length(\Omega_{X/Y})_P\ge e_P$.

The proof proceeds as follows: if $t$ is a local parameter at $Q=f(P)$, then we can write $t=au^{e_P}$, for some unit $a$. So $f^*dt = aeu^{e_P-1}du+au^{e_P}da= aeu^{e_P-1}du$ since $a$ is a unit for this derivation (am I right?).

Now, if the ramification is tame, then $e_P$ is a nonzero element of the field $k$ and we have that the valuation at $P$ of $f^*dt/du = aeu^{e_P-1}$ is indeed $e_P-1$ since the valuation of $ea$ which is invertible is zero.

After that, here comes my favourite part: it considers the other case and states that if the ramification at $P$ is wild then $length(\Omega_{X/Y})_P\ge e_P$, which is...the thesis. I mean, this part of the proof consists in repeating the thesis, which is of course a very concise approach but maybe a bit useless. Again, I'm probably missing something, but I've been missing it for enough time to convince me to ask the question.

Comment: Chapter numbers are pretty helpful when referring to books; I've added them for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason for you to assume $da=0$ - just because an element in a ring is a unit doesn't mean it is sent to 0 by $d$: consider $\Omega_{k(t)/k} = k(t)\cdot dt$, where $t$ is a unit but $dt$ is a nonzero generator. (Also, we'll show that even if $da=0$, you still get the correct result).

Writing $f^*dt = ae_Pu^{e_P-1}du+au^{e_P}da$ and assuming $e_P=0$ in $k$, i.e. wild ramification, then $f^*dt = au^{e_P}da$. Since $\Omega_{X/k,x}\cong\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\cdot du$ for a uniformizer $u$, we must have $da=bdu$ for some $b\in\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Therefore $au^{e_P}da=au^{e_P}b dt$, and $v(au^{e_P}b)=v(a)+v(u^{e_P})+v(b)=e_P+v(b) \geq e_P$ since $v(a)=0$, $v(u)=1$, and $v(b)\geq 0$ (since $b\in\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$).

Comment: By you answer the wild case is very clear. For what concerns the tame case, now I see  why $da$ is not necessarily zero. But so how do I conclude then the equality in this case?

Comment: @Giuseppe $v(au^{e_P}b)\geq e_P$, so since $v(x+y)=\min(v(x),v(y))$ when $v(x)\neq v(y)$ you're done as $v(ae_Pu^{e_P-1})=v(a)+v(e_P)+v(u^{e_P-1})=e_P-1$.

Comment: @Giuseppe it appears you did not upvote this answer. Was that intentional?

Comment: It was not! I did not consider the fact that accepting an answer and upvoting it are both important.